# Why does randomElement() return ?? and not?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm learning Swift and some iOS development. Here is my code which I'm trying to figure out why XCode is complaining.

```
private func rollMyDice() {
    let diceRollImages = [
        UIImage(named: "DiceOne"),
        UIImage(named: "DiceTwo"),
        UIImage(named: "DiceThree"),
        UIImage(named: "DiceFour"),
        UIImage(named: "DiceFive"),
        UIImage(named: "DiceSix")
    ]

    diceOneImageView.image = diceRollImages.randomElement()
    diceTwoImageView.image = diceRollImages.randomElement()
}
```

So in this case, `diceOneImageView.image = diceRollImages.randomElement()` will complain that it cannot assign `UIImage??` to `UIImage?`.

`ImageView.image` is of type `UIImage?`. What I don't understand is why is `randomElement()` here is returning `UIImage??`.

What does `UIImage??` mean? I thought `??` was the nil coalescsing operator, so I'm not sure why it's part of some return type.

Also reading the documentation on `randomElement()`, it should return `?`. So in this case, I would expect `diceRollImages.randomElement()` to return `UIImage?` which should suit `diceOneImageView.image`.

What is happening here? I know I can fix it by using `!` or using nil coalescing etc. to make it work. Just don't get what's going on.

Comment: Notice that `diceRollImages` is a `[UIImage?]`, i.e. each `Element` of the array is optional - `UIImage?`. does it make sense that `randomElement` returns `UIImage??`?

Comment: Yeah I think I know what you mean. It is correct that `diceRollImages` is `[UIImage?`]. So then `randomElement` tries to get `UIImage?` from that collection, then adds another `?` onto it. It does feel pretty weird to express it as `UIImage??`. I would've thought it would compress it and say return type is `UIImage?`. Because I'm not sure if there is a difference between `UIImage??` and `UIImage?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [`UIImage(named:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624146-init) is a failable initialiser, and so the expressions `UIImage(named: "DiceOne")` etc are of type `UIImage?`. This makes the array `diceRollImages` of type `[UIImage?]`. Each `Element` of the array is `UIImage?`, alternatively written as `Optional<UIImage>`.

As you may know, [`Optional`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional) is just an enum with two cases, `.some` and `.none` (aka `nil`). Each element of the array can be:

- `.some(image)`, if a `UIImage` is created successfully from the name
- `.none`, if there is no images with that name

[`randomElement`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994747-randomelement) is declared to return `Element?` (`Optional<Element>`), because the array could have no elements, and hence, cannot give you a random element. `randomElement` returns:

- `.none`, when the array is empty
- `.some(elementOfTheArray)`, when the array is non-empty and `elementOfTheArray` is a random element in array.

Recall that `Element` is `Optional<UIImage>` in the case of `diceRollImages`, and that the array elements (`elementOfTheArray`) could have values `.some(image)` or `.none`.

Therefore, we can say that `randomElement` returns a value of type `Optional<Optional<UIImage>>`, aka `UIImage??`, and it could be one of 3 things:

- `.none` when the array is empty
- `.some(.some(image))` when the array is non-empty and a successfully-created image in the array is randomly selected
- `.some(.none)` when the array is non-empty and a unsuccessfully-created image in the array is random selected

Since you are hardcoding the array of images, you know that the array is not empty, and so it is safe to force-unwrap the outer layer of the optional:

```
diceOneImageView.image = diceRollImages.randomElement()!
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing up what double optionals are. I was having troubles trying to understand the difference between `?` and `??` but I think the 3 cases clears things up. To me, it says `??` can return `nil`, `?` and `??`. I can also imagine cases where you can get even more optional nesting (ie. `???`, `????` etc.)

Comment: An Optional<Optional<T>> is exactly like an Optional<A>, either you have an A or you don't.  Either you have an Optional<T> or you don't.  Nothing special here.  And, if you have an Optional<T>, either it has a value or it doesn't. That's it.

Comment: Of course you can nest optionals to any depth but it's not common because, as in this example, you would generally prefer to compactMap, or 'flatten' out the optionality

Answer (score 1):

The answer has been given already in the comments: `UIImage(named:)` returns (optional) `UIImage?` and the result of calling `randomElement()` on an optional is a double optional `??`

This is a good example where force unwrapping is welcome.

The images are part of the application bundle which is immutable at runtime and the app is useless if one of them is missing.

Declare `diceRollImages`

```
let diceRollImages = [
    UIImage(named: "DiceOne")!,
    UIImage(named: "DiceTwo")!,
    UIImage(named: "DiceThree")!,
    UIImage(named: "DiceFour")!,
    UIImage(named: "DiceFive")!,
    UIImage(named: "DiceSix")!
]
```

If the code crashes nevertheless it reveals a **design** mistake which can be fixed immediately.

You can even force unwrap `randomElement()!` because the array is a constant and is clearly not empty.

Comment: I'm curious if there a better way to define `UIImages` which won't crash at runtime? With `UIImage(named: )` you'll probably run into issues if your string doesn't match an asset. Are `image literals` the safest way to get a `UIImage` which definitely has an asset?

Comment: It cannot crash at runtime because the strings are literals in an array declared as constant (`let`).

Comment: That's correct that it won't crash at runtime because if the parameter passed doesn't exist as an asset, it will return nil. But is there a better way to get a `UIImage` which won't be an optional? That's probably what I was trying to ask.

Comment: You can `guard` all optionals, but practically this is pointless. Force unwrapping is not evil per se if you definitely know that the object **does have** a value. Again assets are created at **design time**.

Comment: PS: And this is what unit tests are for. Write a test to confirm that all assets are available.

Comment: You could use compactMap to remove nils from the array so you have an array of honest UIImage's, e.g ["One", "Two"].compactMap { UIImage(named: "Dice\\($0)" } but force unwrap is ok here because the assets should and must be present